# NullPointer manejando Networkstats para obtener el trafico de datos en android

Tags: android

```
private void loadData(TextView sentMovil, TextView sentWifi, TextView receiverMovil, TextView receiverWifi,
                      TrafficModel trafficModel){


    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        NetworkStats networkStats = null;
        NetworkStatsManager networkStatsManager = null;
        try {
            networkStats = networkStatsManager.querySummary(
                    ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI,
                    "",
                    0,
                    System.currentTimeMillis()
            );

            NetworkStats.Bucket bucket = new NetworkStats.Bucket();
            networkStats.getNextBucket(bucket);

            int absSentWifi = (int) Math.abs(trafficModel.getSentWifi());
            int absReceivedWifi = (int) Math.abs(trafficModel.getReceivedWifi());
            while(networkStats.hasNextBucket()) {
                sentMovil.setText(FormatSize.format(trafficModel.getSentWifi()));
                sentWifi.setText(FormatSize.format(absSentWifi));
                receiverMovil.setText(FormatSize.format(trafficModel.getReceivedWifi()));
                receiverWifi.setText(FormatSize.format(absReceivedWifi));
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Lo anterior es el codigo...justo en la linea debajo del try sale el error...ayuda por favor urgente

Comment: Bienvenido sergio, realiza el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Es **muy importante leer [ask]** que te brinda información de como realizar una pregunta en el sitio, realiza tu pregunta de acuerdo a este documento y obtendrás muy buenas respuestas, agrega una explicación en el cuerpo de la pregunta de lo que deseas y cual es el error, que se despliega en el LogCat?, saludos.

Comment: @sergioceballosfajardo utiliza un star trace para que sepas en que linea del try se esta presentado el error y lo anexas a la pregunta asi sera mas facil ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

El problema del `NullPointerException` probablemente sea porque no has inicializado `networkStatsManager`

```
NetworkStatsManager networkStatsManager = null;
```

Inicializa de la siguiente forma

```
NetworkStatsManager networkStatsManager = context.getSystemService(NetworkStatsManager.class);
```

Esto solucionaria tu problema con el `NullPointerException`